# Event ID 55 on Server 2012

Tags: ntfs, windows-server-2012, raid-1

Keep receiving the following error message in Event viewer on Server 2012.  How do I find out which drive this belongs to.  Have searched but can't find anything useful.  The Server has raid 1 array with a usb bare metal backup drive.

Any help will be greatly appreciated, thank you

```
Log Name:      System
Source:        Ntfs
Date:          23/01/2018 21:23:38
Event ID:      55
Task Category: None
Level:         Error
Keywords:      
User:          SYSTEM
Computer:      ***.****.***
Description:
A corruption was discovered in the file system structure on volume \\?\Volume{0bb31d11-13d9-4525-9b2b-fb8454d1c4c2}.

The exact nature of the corruption is unknown.  The file system structures need to be scanned and fixed offline.

Event Xml:
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
  <System>
    <Provider Name="Ntfs" Guid="{DD70BC80-EF44-421B-8AC3-CD31DA613A4E}" />
    <EventID>55</EventID>
    <Version>0</Version>
    <Level>2</Level>
    <Task>0</Task>
    <Opcode>0</Opcode>
    <Keywords>0x8000000000000000</Keywords>
    <TimeCreated SystemTime="2018-01-23T21:23:38.699388100Z" />
    <EventRecordID>873158</EventRecordID>
    <Correlation />
    <Execution ProcessID="4" ThreadID="6560" />
    <Channel>System</Channel>
        <Security UserID="S-1-5-18" />
  </System>
  <EventData>
    <Data Name="DriveName">\\?\Volume{0bb31d11-13d9-4525-9b2b-fb8454d1c4c2}</Data>
    <Data Name="DeviceName">\Device\HarddiskVolume491</Data>
    <Data Name="CorruptionState">0x11</Data>
    <Data Name="HeaderFlags">0x802</Data>
    <Data Name="Severity">Critical</Data>
    <Data Name="Origin">File System Driver</Data>
    <Data Name="Verb">Force Full Chkdsk</Data>
    <Data Name="Description">The exact nature of the corruption is unknown.  The file system structures need to be scanned and fixed offline.
</Data>
    <Data Name="Signature">0x6c3cf718</Data>
    <Data Name="Outcome">Pseudo Verb</Data>
    <Data Name="SampleLength">0</Data>
    <Data Name="SampleData">
    </Data>
    <Data Name="SourceFile">0x17</Data>
    <Data Name="SourceLine">193</Data>
    <Data Name="SourceTag">137</Data>
    <Data Name="CallStack">Ntfs+0x1cd4f5, Ntfs+0x457f6, Ntfs+0x2fd6f, Ntfs+0xd1ef4, ntoskrnl+0x1516f7, ntoskrnl+0x1516bd, ntoskrnl+0x2ebfd, Ntfs+0xd0e1f, ntoskrnl+0x3c4db9, ntoskrnl+0x4789d2, ntoskrnl+0x49d04e, ntoskrnl+0x3c8e93, ntoskrnl+0x42fddb, ntoskrnl+0x42f967, ntoskrnl+0x48e53d, Ntfs+0x8ae56, Ntfs+0x8b060, Ntfs+0x9d3f3, Ntfs+0x9c70f, Ntfs+0xa886, ntoskrnl+0x7471f, ntoskrnl+0x67074, ntoskrnl+0x1543c6</Data>
  </EventData>
</Event>
```

Answer (score 0):

The following solutions require that the offending disk be currently connected to the system. Using the Volume GUID from the event text (e.g. `\\?\Volume{0bb31d11-13d9-4525-9b2b-fb8454d1c4c2}`) you can identify the corresponding volume and the hard disk that owns it.

### Method 1: Use PowerShell

1. Run the following commands from an elevated PowerShell prompt:

   ```
   $VolumeGUID = '\\?\Volume{3b06bdca-59f9-11e2-bec8-806e6f6e6963}\'
   Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Volume | Where {$_.DeviceID -eq $VolumeGUID} | Select DriveLetter,Label,DeviceID | FL
   ```

   **Note:** Substitute your specific volume GUID from the event text in the first command.

   If available, this will return the volume Drive Letter and Label of the corresponding disk. Use this to identify the disk:

   [image]

### Method 2: Use WinObj

1. Download and run [WinObj](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/winobj) from Microsoft's SysInternals site. This tool allows you to navigate the Object Manager namespace.
2. In the left pane, select the **GLOBAL??** node
3. Sort the right pane by the **Name** column, then find the Volume GUID.

   **Note:** The disk must be currently connected to the system for it to be listed in WinObj.

   [image]
4. Make note of the entry's SymLink value
5. Sort the data by the *SymLink* column
6. Find the entries that match the value from step 4.  There should be several. Look for an entry in the format `\Device\Harddisk#Parition#`:

   [image]
7. Open the Disk Management MMC snap-in (run `diskmgmt.msc`)
8. Identify the disk and volume (partition) using the information from step 6. For reference, Disk 0 in Disk Manager corresponds to Harddisk0 from WinObj, and partitions are also numbered starting at 0:
   [image]